# Trocar endereço padrão utilizado pelo Docker (172.17.0.1)

Tags: linux, docker, redes, mint

Eu gostaria de trocar (ou remover) o endereço 172.17.0.1 utilizado pelas redes do docker, tem como fazer isso?

Eu utilizo docker para desenvolvimento php e tenho um repositório remoto (git) configurado através de uma VPN utilizando a faixa de IP 172.17.X.X.

Sempre que meus containers estão up, a rede do docker utiliza essa faixa de IP e eu fico impossibilitado de fazer qualquer requisição ao repositório remoto.

Obrigado.

OBS: Eu utilizo um ambiente Linux (Mint 19)

---

Consegui resolver meu problema, definindo uma subnet na rede utilizada pelos meus containers no arquivo docker-compose.yml. Dessa forma:

```
networks:
  frontend:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 172.18.0.0/16
  backend:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 172.19.0.0/16
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As configurações da rede padrão (`bridge` ) do *Docker* podem ser alteradas editando o arquivo `daemon.json`, no diretório `/etc/docker/`. Segue um exemplo do arquivo `daemon.json`:

```
 {
  "bip": "192.168.1.5/24",
  "fixed-cidr": "192.168.1.5/25",
  "fixed-cidr-v6": "2001:db8::/64",
  "mtu": 1500,
  "default-gateway": "10.20.1.1",
  "default-gateway-v6": "2001:db8:abcd::89",
  "dns": ["10.20.1.2","10.20.1.3"]
}
```

Uma opção seria configurar uma nova rede, usando o `docker network create ...`

Na documentação você ver mais informações, sobre os [*drivers* de rede disponíveis](https://docs.docker.com/network/#network-drivers), [como configurar uma nova rede](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network_create/) e como [alterar as configurações de `bridge` padrão](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/#connect-a-container-to-the-default-bridge-network).

Comment: Eu já havia incluído nesse arquivo uma configuração para a rede bridge começar pelo 172.30.0.1 (coloquei apenas a opção bip). Será que eu tenho que especificar todas as opções que são indicadas na doc? Obrigado

Comment: O seu `daemon.json` tá igual esse da documentação?

Comment: Não. Está um json com a opção bip apenas.

Comment: Eu não entendi se o gateway e se o dns devem ser definidos com base na minha rede real ou deixar esses valores padrões mesmo. Por isso deixei só a opção bep

Comment: Na doc fala que você edita apenas o que for customizar (*Only specify the settings you need to customize.*), pode deixar o seu `daemon` só o `bip` mesmo. Reiniciou o *Docker* depois que fez as alterações?

Comment: Sim. Reiniciei sim

Comment: Então.. eu recomendaria você configurar uma nova `bridge` e adicionar no `daemon.json`(`{"bridge" : "minha_rede"}`)  , normalmente só com isso já era pra ter dado certo.